Plang: How do I send a reminder to write food entry
In the https://github.com/ingig/FoodDiaryApp, how can I make the app remind me to write my food entry. I would like it send me reminder at 8pm, since I should have stopped eating at that time
I don't know what to do to make this work, I know I need to write some plang code, but I am not sure how to do that

You need to change your Start.goal file, open the file in your text editor. Find the line - call !ShowTotalCalories, above or below(doesn't matter) that line add this code
- call goal !SetupSchedule

Then scroll to the bottom of the file and add this
SetupSchedule
- every day at 20:00, call !SendReminder

SendReminder
/ Check if I have any entries today, I dont want to send if I have added already
- select * from food_entries where date is today, write to %entries%
/ if I haven't created any entry, remind me
- if %entries% is empty then
    - call goal !SendMessage content="Don't forget to add to your diary"

now you need to build the code, open the terminal/command and go to the folder where Start.goal is located, run this command
plang build

It will now send you a message at 20:00 (8pm) to remind you to add your food entry.
